# Can't use Theme.Holo for styles of my first Android app

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I'm developing my first Android app following the official Android tutorial, so I'm new, but when I try to styling the action bar with the `Theme.Holo` my app crash down during the starting, into the log I've the following message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

I know that if I use the `Theme.AppCompact` it's working, but in the tutorial does not mention problems like this one with the Theme.Holo, and does not give a solution, because if I use the Theme.AppCompact the app works, but I can't modify the style of the action bar with a custom color or with a background image.

I've followed exactly the tutorial until this point: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html
make an exception for the minSdkVersion, in the tutorial is set to 8, I've changed the value to 14 because gives me other compatibility problems.

This is the **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycompany.myfirstapp" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MyActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

</manifest>
```

**Themes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>


<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                //openSearch();
                Log.i("MyActivity", "SEARCH PRESSED");
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                //openSettings();
                Log.i("MyActivity", "SETTINGS PRESSED");
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**activity_my.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**main_activity_actions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: *if i use the Theme.AppCompact the app works, but i can't modify the style of the action bar with a custom color or with a background image.* why not?

Comment: i've set a background image using "@drawable/actionbar_background", with the corresponding png file, or a color like "#AA0000", but using the Theme.AppCompact does not consider them

Comment: Where is the actual question here? Seems more like a statement than a question.

Comment: i want to know why using Theme.Holo gives error and why using the Theme.AppCompact i can't change the style of the action bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to the questions in your comment

> I want to know why using Theme.Holo gives error and why using the Theme.AppCompact I can't change the style of the action bar

are in the tutorial you are reading.

> Note: If you are using the Support Library APIs for the action bar, then you must use (or override) the Theme.AppCompat family of styles (rather than the Theme.Holo family, available in API level 11 and higher).

You are using the **Support Library** with `AppCompatActivity` hence you must use `Theme.AppCompat`. As to why you can't change the style of the Action Bar that is most likely because you are not using the correct section of the tutorial. Because you are using the Support Library to customise the Action Bar you must use the section **For Android 2.1 and higher** in the [Styling the Action Bar tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html).

That is `res/values/themes.xml` should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Note the use of **Theme.AppCompat** and the lines which add compatibility for the Support Library

```
<!-- Support library compatibility -->
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
```

and

```
<!-- Support library compatibility -->
<item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
```

---

The Action Bar did not exist pre Android 3.0. Backwards compatibility for it is provided using the Support Library. Hence, because you are using the Support Library to get the desired effects you need to follow all of the advice for Android 2.1 (pre Android 3.0).

Comment: I thought that changing the minSdkVersion from 8 to 14 I could follow the "For Android 3.0 and higher only" section of the tutorial, now with your changes i can view the background image, but i can't set an hexa color like #AA0000, because the line of the support library gives me an error "Cannot resolve symbol", how can i solve this?

Comment: But you are still using the Support Library and so you need to be compatible with that. All `minSdkVersion` does is prevent your app from being installed on devices that don't meet that requirement. You should **ask a new question** about the hex value problem. I could guess at a solution but that would be a waste of time and isn't how [so] operates.

Comment: ok, got it, thank you, i will ask a new question for the the hex color

Answer (score 0):

make this change:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>


<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What exactly is the change? And why should he apply it?

Comment: With this change the app works but i can't change the style of the action bar, i can't see the background image or an edited color like "#AA0000"

Comment: He need to change it because he extends AppCompatActivity in MyActivity

Comment: @MattC IKavanagh's answer is right, because you are using support library remove prefix "android:"

Comment: @rainash  now with the his changes i can view the background image, but i can't set an hexa color like #AA0000, because the line of the support library gives me an error "Cannot resolve symbol", how can i solve this?

Comment: @MattC  add item ` <item name="colorPrimary">#aa0000</item>` remember do not add android: prefix

Answer (score 0):

you have to just change in style.xml

Replace Parent

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"   parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

</style>
```

to

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#AA0000</item>
</style>
```

**AND**

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
```

to

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
```

Comment: With the Theme.AppCompact the app works but the style changes makes not effect, the action bar is dark, doesn not have the "@drawable/actionbar_background" png background

Comment: Edited my answer just please check